GitHub Actions - Possible to Compile JS and either create / modify file in branch
I'm trying to automate my deployment in GitHub, we have JS files that we want to uglify and minify. Locally we use Gulp and it works well for us. It uglifies and minifies all the files and creates a .min.js file for us.
Since moving over to Github we want Github Actions to do this for us. We have tried updating the gulp file and it runs without any issues, it finds the JS without issues but we aren't seeing the minified output js files in the branch.
I have set Github Actions to have read and write permissions so it should be capable of it.
Is there something I am missing or is Github Actions not capable of it?
Build.yml
name: Compile Assets

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main", "development" ]

permissions: write-all

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [22.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: npm install
    
    - name: Build Assets
      run: gulp

gulpfile.js
import { src, dest, task, series } from 'gulp'; // Base Gulp Functionality
import terser from 'gulp-terser'; // Uglify + Minify JS
import rename from "gulp-rename"; // Rename files
import sourcemaps from "gulp-sourcemaps"; // Create Map Files 


task("test", function() {
        return src(["src/*.js", "!src/.*.js", "!src/*.min.js"]) // Read JS Files Ignore Minified / Mac files, set relative path starting from that file
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // Create SourceMaps
            .pipe(terser()) // Uglify + Minify them
            .pipe(rename(function (path) { 
                path.extname = ".min.js"; // Update .js to .min.js
            }))
            .pipe(dest("dest/")); // Save minified to save folder

});


task("default", series("test"));

I've tried different permutations of this, ones where the output files already exist in the destination folder and ones where its empty.
Is there any advice to get this to work? Thank you.

"Locally we use Gulp and it works well for us. It uglifies and minifies all the files and creates a .min.js file for us." What you usually do with said .min.js file? "I have set Github Actions to have read and write permissions…" But you need to send generated file(s) somewhere. Github Actions don't work directly with repositories, if you want to see the generated file(s) in your repository you need to add, commit and push.

So if Github Actions runs the Gulp file and generates the files, do I then need to add and commit them as well within the github action?

If you want to commit the minified files to the repo then yes, it won't do that automatically. But it would be quite unusual to do that unless the goal is to deploy to Github Pages. Normally you'd just upload the minified files to the server as part of the deploy process and discard them at the end.

@StevenGray You didn't answer my 1st question: what you usually do with said .min.js file? Do you commit and push it? Or send it somewhere else? You should do the same from the Github Actions workflow: add+commit+push; or send it over FTP/rsync/scp/whatever. Github Actions workflows run in virtual machines that don;t have direct access to anything but the have $GITHUB_TOKEN that allows to push back to the origin repository. They also have network connection so you can write files over the network.

@phd Push it to the branch with the other files that were just pushed.

@StevenGray Do that as the last step of the workflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-actions%5D+push+back for examples
